# Casting a collection of a specific type to a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

Is it possible to cast a collection of objects (using one of it's string properties) to a string array, without having to go into a loop?

I.e:

MailAddress[] items have a string property 'Address' which I'd like to pull into a string[] in a one-liner, if possible.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I'm sure if the op felt like it they could override `ToString()` but that is really overkill and isn't what its there for ;)

Comment: Do you want array (as in `string[]`) or "array-like" (class with indexer) would work? If yes than you can wrap your array with such class and have it return property you want to avoid any loop (direct or hidden with LINQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

string[] addresses = items.Select(mailAddress => mailAddress.Address).ToArray();
```

Comment: Right, LINQ uses loop under a cover.

Comment: @pwas I meant that I didn't want to define the loop myself :) This is elegant and exactly what I need, thanks.